# why do I keep getting a 503 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Project currently hosted locally via IIS Express.

However, I want this to be accessible to one of our clients for a demonstration, I have got this to work before, However after deleting a couple of redundant sites from applicationhost.config, and subsequently adding the details for my current site, it has ceased to function, when I go to my IP, E.G xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:85 it comes back with a 503 error.

I was wondering if anyone could help me pinpoint this problem? my applicationhost.config appears to be fine, though I have pasted that in below for reference.

I have already tried setting the Application Pool Identity to Network Service, and to my own local account, I have also set "load user Profile" to false, but with no avail.

I have also disabled windows firewall for testing purposes, so I know that's not part of the issue either.

Any and all help would be most appreciated!

By the way, the below is the only part of applicationhost.config I've modified, the rest is not included.

```
<applicationPools>
            <add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr4ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="UnmanagedClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Classic" autoStart="true" />

          <add name="DefaultAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />


            <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeLoader="v4.0">
                <processModel />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>

        <!--

          The <listenerAdapters> section defines the protocols with which the
          Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) binds.

        -->
        <listenerAdapters>
            <add name="http" />
        </listenerAdapters>

        <sites>


<site name="hendrixlivetest" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\reece\Desktop\myprojectfile" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:85:" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:85:w" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:85:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" />

    </bindings>
</site>


            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application pool is getting crashed. try and reinstall .NET 4 framework and try again on server